# Adding image to element using appendChild yields error

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I have this function running on my `window.onload` function (so the elements exist before it runs)

```
var img = new Image();
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('myButtons');

img.onload = function () {
    button.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = 'icons/buttons/fav.png'
```

However, when I execute this, I get a return of:

```
button.appendChild is not a function
```

additionally, I'd like to add a class on to this image
I should note as well that I am not using the `<button>` tag and am instead using this:

`<span><a href="#" class="myButton" id="name">text</a></span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a [collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a single button. A collection is similar to an array, but not quite the same. If you want to loop over the collection using `.forEach` you can use the spread syntax `...` to move the contents from the collection into an array. Using this array you can then loop over each button within it, and then use `.innerHTML` to add the image to each button.

Additionally, to add an class to the image you can use `img.classList.add()`

See working example below:

```js
var img = new Image();
var buttons = [...document.getElementsByClassName('myButton')];
img.src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a';

img.classList.add('img-btn');

img.onload = function() {
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    img.id = button.id + '1';
    button.innerHTML += img.outerHTML;
  });
};
```

```css
.img-btn {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<span><a href="#" class="myButton" id="name1">Btn 1</a></span>
<span><a href="#" class="myButton" id="name2">Btn 2</a></span>
<span><a href="#" class="myButton" id="name3">Btn 3</a></span>
```

Also note, using `.appendChild()` will "move" the img from button to button, you need to use `.innerHTML` to append the img to multiple buttons.

Comment: I should have probably also pointed out my buttons are `<a>` elements within `<spans>` I think that will affect this.

Comment: @CollinWillson no this shouldn't affect the result if you update the class name. See my updated snippet.

Comment: Brilliant. This was perfect, works exactly as expected. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nick, would it be easy to make the image share the id of the element it is coming from? Specifically the `<a>` element?

Comment: @CollinWillson it is possible, but the issue with that is that id’s should be unique to each element. So making it have the same id wouldn’t be valid HTML and can cause errors down the line. What would be valid would be to give the element an additional class which is the same as the id of the button it is on

Comment: Ah, I understand. I could live with adding that id and putting a `1` at the end of it. That way it's different...

Comment: @CollinWillson ok, I've updated my answer to do what you want. If you right-click the button and click Inspect and go to the `img` you'll be able to see that it has an id applied to it now (based on its button)

Comment: That is awesome, you rock

Answer (score 0):

That's because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns of type `Array`. `Array` does not have a function named `appendChild`. You probably should use an index to access the button element, like, `button[0].appendChild(img)` or use a `for` statement to loop through all the buttons.

You can add a class to the image like this.

`img.classList.add("myImageClass");`

Comment: It doesn't yield any errors but it also does not do anything

Comment: That's probably has to do something with your image resource. Maybe its way too small to see any change to the UI. Why don't you set the src to something bigger like set the src to this: `https://via.placeholder.com/150`